# Understanding a Computer Architecture Problem

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

> Below, we have given you four different sequences of addresses generated by a program
>   running on a processor with a data cache. Cache hit ratio for each sequence is also shown
>   below.
>
> \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
> \hline
> Sequence No. & Address Sequence & Hit Ratio \\ \hline
>  1& 0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 &0.50\\ \hline
>  2&0, 1024, 2048, 3072, 4096, 3072, 2048, 1024, 0  &0.33 \\ \hline
>  3&0, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 0  &4/9 \\ \hline
> 4& 0, 512, 2048, 0, 1536, 0, 1024, 512   &0.25 \\ \hline
> \end{array}
>
> Assumptions: all memory accesses are one byte accesses. All addresses are byte addresses. Assuming that the cache is initially empty at the beginning of each sequence, find out the
>   following parameters of the processors data cache:
>
> 1. Associativity (1, 2 or 4 ways) (4 points)
> 2. Block size (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32 bytes) (4 points)
> 3. Total cache size (1024 B or 2048 B) (4 points)
> 4. Replacement policy (LRU or FIFO) (4 points)
>
> Please justify (explain) your answers.

I can't understand what they are asking. When they say "find out the following parameters of the processors data cache", do they mean that I have to choose one of these parameters that fits the logic in the table? Can you better explain what I have to do in this problem?

Comment: For caches with different parameters, those address sequences would all get different hit ratios. You have to deduce what kind of parameters would give the hit ratios shown.

Comment: This problem is designed to make you review the course material and then do basic arithmetics. I suggest you do so.

Comment: I think I got it. I took number theory and abstract algebra. I found an application of congruence in this exercise. I feel happy that I finally found some meaning in having taken these courses.

Comment: @Raphael I need help. Consider this link and take a look at page 10/10 http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ece447/s13/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=hw5_solution.pdf. For the total cache size, why do they say that For sequence 3, a total cache size of 512 B will give a hit rate of 4/9 with a 4-way associative cache and 8
byte blocks regardless of the replacement policy, which is higher than 0.33. If we consider a 512 B cache then the numer of sets is $(512/8)/4=16$. All 0, 64, 128, 256, 512 are congruent to 0 mod (16), so they all map to the same set which means at 512 we have to make a replacement.

Comment: This will lead to 3/9 hits since one piece of data was flushed by the replacement.